# Is it impossible to model a homomorphic hash function as a random oracle?

Tags: hash, random-oracle-model

Recall that, by definition, on input a query $q$, a random oracle $H$ can output a fresh random string as its response $H(q)$ (if this query has not been seen before).

**My understanding.** A homomorphic hash $HH$ allows someone to compute $HH(a + b)$ from two hash values $HH(a)$ and $HH(b)$. Since $HH(a + b)$ is dependent on $HH(a)$ and $HH(b)$, its value is not randomly distributed as the one generated by a random oracle. So, it is safe to conclude that $HH$ is not a random oracle.

Is my understanding correct? Or is there any special random oracle model can be used to model a homomorphic hash function? Many thanks.

Comment: I might be wrong, but from what I know, an evenly-distributed output isn't a necessary condition to random oracle; and it's necessary that, at least observer cannot predict the result of new input based on past observation.

Comment: Ask the $HH$ the hash of one $x = HH(1)$ then you know the rest of the hashes, i.e. you own the hash, and actually, you may even perform faster than asking another one if you build your table with $2^1,2^1,2^2, \ldots, 2^\ell$ where $\ell$.